# Connect to the computer running at home when outside at coffee

Tags: ssh

When at home,  I can connect to another computer using ssh

```
 ssh assistant@pc.local -p 2222
```

if go outside and try to connect to the computer running at home

```
me@alpha:~$ ssh assistant@beta.remote -p 2222
ssh: Could not resolve hostname assistant.remote: Name or service not known

me@alpha:~$ ssh assistant@beta -p 2222
ssh: Could not resolve hostname assistant: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

How to get it done?

Comment: ... or [Step by Step enable remote login to home ubuntu machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921909/step-by-step-enable-remote-login-to-home-ubuntu-machine)

Comment: The router at home has to have port forwarding configured.  Also, you have to `ssh` into router ip address, so that it can send connection to the machine you specify via port forwarding. That is , if your router is ip `10.20.30.40`, you should do `ssh -p 2222 assistant@10.20.30.40 `. Of course, without port forwarding this won't work.

Comment: How succinct the answer.O(∩_∩)O @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: @Alice It's a comment, though if you want me to post it as an answer I could. But it essentially repeats what I said in the duplicate. Succinct or not , I hope it helps you and is useful